nodemailer not passing user and pass in React app on server - how to replace .env credentials?
TLDR is, I think I know what issue is, but do not know how to fix it:)
I have written my react app with simple contact section.
Secondly, I have coded nodemailer node.js backend for handling login and form of the e-mail. Credentials for nodemailer were passed through .env and it worked flawlessly in localhost. (Please note both .env and sendtoemail.js are being located in the app folder where index.html is, not in src or public)
import express, { json } from "express";
import { createTransport } from "nodemailer";
import cors from "cors";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import "dotenv/config";

const app = express();
const USER = process.env.EMAIL_USER;
const PASS = process.env.EMAIL_PASS;

const corsOrigin = {
  origin: "https://mywebpage.com",
};

app.use(cors(corsOrigin));
app.use(json());
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post("/send-contact", async (req, res) => {
  const { name, email, message } = req.body;
  try {
    let transporter = createTransport({
      host: "myhost.com",
      port: 465,
      secure: true,
      auth: {
        user: USER,
        pass: PASS,
      },
    });

    let mailOptions = {
      from: email,
      to: USER,
      subject: `Nowa wiadomość od ${name}`,
      text: message,
      html: `<p><strong>Nadawca:</strong> ${name} </p>
    <p><strong>Email:</strong> ${email}</p>
    <p><strong>Wiadomość:</strong> ${message}</p>`,
    };
    await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions);
    transporter.verify(function (error, success) {
      if (error) {
        console.log(error);
      } else {
        console.log("Server is ready to take our messages");
      }
    });

    res.status(200).json({ message: "Email sent successfully!" });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error sending email:", error);
    res
      .status(500)
      .json({ message: "Error sending email", error: error.toString() });
  }
});

And when I had built my app by npm run build and upladed it on server (I have just domain with server folders such as public-html, nothing like firebase or similar) it does not log in or send my form.
I think I know why it does not work - it probably does not read or even build my node.js script + .env, but I do not not know how to safely fix it. Any help would be highly appreciated :)
I want to be sure that I by mistake I do not pass .env credentials to my public folder

You can upload or create a .env file on the server. Please remove the React code and tag. It's unrelated to your question. Then, you can also remove the TypeScript tag, because there is no TypeScript in your backend code. "how to replace .env credentials?" What build system do you use for the backend? "And when I had built my app by npm run build and upladed it on server" Do you actually run the backend on your server?

If I correctly understand the description, you have to start here: What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming? The React code is client-side code and runs in the browser. The backend/Express code is server-side code. It's expected to be run with a Node.js runtime environment on the server. You need an application server, either this Node.js code or in a different language, e.g. PHP.

Host your Node.JS Backend separately from the React Frontend app and create a .env file in the Remote Backend project.
You can try setting up dotenv this way.
import * as dotenv from "dotenv";
dotenv.config();

